# How do I send every message in discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So basically I want to recreate every discord channel in the console

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

b = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ".")
b.remove_command("help")

@b.event
async def on_message():
    print("What ever message the user sent")

b.run('token')
```

Every time a user sends a message, the message will be copied to the console. Is this possible? Also, is it possible to see what user sent it and what channel it is in? I know you can get channel and author IDs, but what about channel names and usernames?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@b.event
async def on_message(message):
    await b.process_commands(message)
    print(f"{message.author} in {message.channel} : {message.content}")
```

That should give you the message with the sender and where the message came from.

Comment: It works but it gives an error after every message, ignoring exception in command: none, and then who the command I typed is not found.

Comment: Can you show me the exact error and what you typed to trigger it? I don't see this when I type a message.

Comment: I actually figured it out, I set the prefix as nothing so it took every message as a command, I probably should've looked over my code before asking, it was a mistake from me, sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Oh, okay then. Happy coding!